# why required interface's item's in mongoose Schema are optional?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I try to add interface to my mongoose schema and develop my interface with required item but when I add my interface to my schema all item's in get optional item's ...

I have a **interface** with **typescript** something like this:

```
interface IPersonnelModel {
  branchId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  personnelNumber: string;
  password: string;
  email: string;
  machineId: [string];
}
```

when we add our interface to a function, model, class ... must be follow the exact item's in the typescript otherwise we get typescript error's.

and when I want to add optional item adding something like this:

```
interface IPersonnelModel {
  branchId?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  personnelNumber?: string;
  password?: string;
  email?: string;
  machineId?: [string];
}
```

when I try to add required or optional item's mongoose schema know all item's as optional.

why it's can't be like the normal typescript ?